# Доступ к статическим файлам в ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Для статических файлов в проекте ASP.NET Core MVC есть папка wwwroot. Но можно ли использовать файлы (в моем случае изображения), которые лежат в другом месте на диске?

Метод UseDirectoryBrowser позволяет просматривать содержимое каталогов не в папке wwwroot:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDirectoryBrowser();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\Photo"),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/images")
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Но при этом можно перемещаться по структуре каталогов, но открытие файла изображения выдает ошибку: "Изображение не может быть показано, так как содержит ошибки".

Или приложение ASP.NET Core обязывает помещать все статические файлы только в папку wwwroot?

Answer (score 5):

Разобрался. Если использовать метод UseFileServer, то все работает:

```
        app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
        {
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\Photo"),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/images"),
            EnableDefaultFiles = false
        });
```

Comment: Надо только иметь ввиду, что большинство (облачных) провайдеров запрещают доступ к произвольным папкам на диске, как минимум надо включать в настройках. Иначе можно оказаться в ситуации, когда папка при каждом развёртывании удаляется напрочь со всем содержимым.